Why am I getting darker results in RGB grid volume rendering?
I am rendering an RGB volume. The volume is 4D: (X, Y, Z, D), with D = 3 (RGB values). Previously I am able to render the mono-chromatic volume, using exact the same idea presented in pbr-book: sampling volume scattering and the code is very similar to that of Falcor: GridVolumeSampler.slang (function: evalTransmittanceRatioTracking and sampleDistanceDeltaTracking). Now when I extended the same approach to RGB volume, I took the following way:

Sample an RGB channel, PDF based on the normalized throughput (vec3) * majorant (vec3)
Evaluate the single channel path throughput (or sampled distance)
Use the following code to output vector3f value path throughput:

# pdf here is the pdf of sampling the channel
if self._type == GridVolume_np.RGB:
    if channel == 0:
        result[:3] = vec3([Tr / pdf, 0, 0])
    elif channel == 1:
        result[:3] = vec3([0, Tr / pdf, 0])
    else:
        result[:3] = vec3([0, 0, Tr / pdf])
else:
    result[:3] = vec3([Tr, Tr, Tr]) 

As can be seen, the only difference here should be:

If the volume is mono-chromatic, vec3([Tr, Tr, Tr]) will be returned, as if we treat the RGB volume as an 1-channel volume, so the code logic is equivalent to the mono-chromatic version.
If the volume is RGB, we set the other two channels not selected to 0, and the selected channel as Tr / pdf. This should effectively retain unbiasedness, since the expectation of the transmittance is exactly what's wanted:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\pmb{T}_{r}) = (\frac{T_{r,1}}{p_1}, 0, 0)\times p_1 + (0, \frac{T_{r,2}}{p_2}, 0)\times p_2 + (0, 0, \frac{T_{r,3}}{p_3})\times p_3\tag{taking expectation}\\
= (T_{r,1}, T_{r,2}, T_{r,3})
$$
But here is what I get:



one bounce (mono)
one bounce (RGB)
2 bounce (mono)
2 bounce (RGB)










4 bounce (mono)
4 bounce (RGB)
32 bounce (mono)
32 bounce (RGB)









The rendering clamps the surface bounce to 1, the table header indicates how many bounces allowed in the medium. For 1-medium-bounce case, the two kinds of volume are identical. Yet since the second bounce, RGB volume is significantly darker than mono-chromatic medium. The gap is increasing as the bounce increases.
Why is this happening? I am guessing, since the 1-bounce case is good, there should be something wrong with distance sampling function or path termination condition.
For the sake of completeness, my code for the volume sampling and transmittance estimation can be found here, commit:
852d73a, and the volumetric path tracing logic can be found here, commit:
852d73a. Leave a comment if you need the volume asset. I've been working on this for two days without finding any valuable clue... so any help is appreciated.

Update
I kinda solved this, but I still can not understand the reason. It turns out it has something to do with distance sampling path throughput and Russian Roulette. At first when I comment out the RGB volume Tr / pdf part and use vec3([Tr, Tr, Tr]) and leave the transmittance estimator with Tr / pdf, everything works perfectly. So I revert the comment and go to delete the Russian Roulette code, and I get:



8 bounces, no change (RGB)
8 bounces, no change (mono)
8 bounces, RR turned off (RGB)










So my question now becomes: why will writing vec3([Tr, Tr, Tr]) to single channel Tr / pdf influence RR?
